# how to get a list of your own Facebook developer apps

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am creating a page for Facebook Fanpage Owner to login. Once they login, it'll show a list of Fanpages that they own.  Which api should I use to get a list of apps/fanpages that the login user owns?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermine, I know how to do it now.   Basically, all you need to do is to call a

https://graph.facebook.com//accounts